# express language выводится как текст при подключении js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Когда скрипты прописал в отдельном js-файле, то не распознает express language, т.е. берет как текст (list_name=${listName}). Если же скрипт весит в самой jsp, то подменяет на нужный лист.

```
    $("#doneTask").click(function () {
    var param = $('#tableTask :checked').serialize() + '&list_name=${listName}' + '&updateCommand=done';
    alert(param);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: '/listControllers/UpdateController', 
        data: param, 

        success: function (response) { 
//                        alert(response);
            if (response) {
                $('#res').html(response); 
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
//                alert(xhr.status); 
//                alert(thrownError); 
        },

    });
});
```

Т.е. alert выводит checkTask=237&list_name=${listName}&updateCommand=done

Comment: потому что js файлы не обрабатываются jsp

Comment: @ Grundy и какие варианты решить вопрос

Comment: Два варианта: настроить, чтобы js файлы тоже обрабатывались, либо перенести код в jsp

Comment: @ Grundy подскажите как настроить?

Comment: Неа, без понятий как конфигурируется jsp

Comment: [но похожий вопрос может помочь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4991651/2881286)

Comment: [или вот](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6608644/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Уж прошу прощения за то, что вмешался, но решение ведь простое, точнее их 2.

1) Сделать onClick="sendAjax(${listName})"

2)

```
<a id="doneTask" data-listName="${listName}">Кнопка я</a> и
```

```js
  $("#doneTask").click(function () {
    var listName = $(this).data('listName');
    var param = $('#tableTask :checked').serialize() + '&list_name=' + listName + '&updateCommand=done';
    alert(param);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: '/listControllers/UpdateController', 
        data: param, 

        success: function (response) { 
//                        alert(response);
            if (response) {
                $('#res').html(response); 
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 
//                alert(xhr.status); 
//                alert(thrownError); 
        },

    });
});
```